# Django, error when trying to add search fields in the admin interface

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am trying to add a search field in admin interface for my `UserProfile` class.

This is my `models.py`:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=None, null=True,
                             related_name='profile')  # don't judge me. I had to use null=True
    registered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activated = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    activation_key = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    receive_notifications = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=80, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.email
```

And this is my `admin.py`:

```
from main.models import UserProfile
from django.contrib import admin

class UserProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ['email']

admin.site.register(UserProfileAdmin)
```

When I try to run the server I get this error:

`'MediaDefiningClass' object is not iterable` at the line where I register `UserProfileAdmin`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
admin.site.register(UserProfileAdmin)
```

Should be

```
admin.site.register(UserProfile, UserProfileAdmin)
```